# Is there a package or way of altering file charset encoding in PL/SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, encoding, plsql, oracle11g

So the problem is as follows: Oracle receives some files in one type of old DOS Russian char encoding (OEM 866), Database itself uses windows-1251 char encoding, and data becomes rubbish inside database, what are the ways in PL/SQL to change encoding of the income files, convert them, and afterwards convert them back. Preferably using Pl/Sql and not anything else, or something very efficient. Other option is please explain how to write a converter myself.

Thanks in advance

Comment: How are you getting and handling the files; are you reading then with `UTL_FILE`?

Comment: Example code to change your variable encoding:

    DECLARE
     vClob CLOB;
     vString varchar2 (1024);
    BEGIN
     vString := 'rpo14525716_650120140520_007809###
     35;Нет клиента и счета в Банке: 40702810608560006628.@@@
     2014-05-20@@@
     11:18:24@@@
     ===';
     vString := convert(vString, 'CL8MSWIN1251', 'RU8PC866');
     dbms_output.put_line(vString);
   END;
    /

From specification:

    CONVERT(char, dest_char_set[, source_char_set ])

All available encodings:

    SELECT * FROM V$NLS_VALID_VALUES WHERE parameter = 'CHARACTERSET' and value like '%866%'